# How to change the background by use Image_path and BitmapDrawable?

Tags: android, background, bitmap

I want to change the background for Activity.

I choose a picture in `Fragment`.

Use intent and transmit the path to Activity.

The Activity receive the path but when I set the background for the Activity , it crash.

The following code is in Activity:

```
 public class Splash extends Activity {

    public static final String BACKGROUND_PATH = "path";
    private String Background_path;
    private static final String TAG = "MJPEG Player" ;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ;


        // Hides the titlebar
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) ;

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        Background_path = intent.getStringExtra(BACKGROUND_PATH);
        Log.i(TAG, "Background_path = " + Background_path);

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);

        if(Background_path != null) {
            BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(Background_path);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            Log.i(TAG, "background = " + background);
        }

    setContentView(R.layout.splash) ;
```

And the error log is like the following:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(20747): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(20747): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416cc450)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(20747): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4786)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:47)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
E/AndroidRuntime(20747):    ... 11 more
W/System.err(20747): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.1.1/cgi-bin/liveMJPEG
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.Splash
W/ActivityManager(  568):   Force finishing activity tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer/.MainActivity
```

The `tw.com.a_i_t.IPCamViewer.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:47)` is `relativeLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(background);`

Does someone can teach me how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is

```
 setContentView(R.layout.splash) ;
```

Then initialize views. But you have it at the last

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash) ; // first set the layout to the activity
relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash); // then initialize your views
```

Comment: Thanks! but when I close the APP , the background return to the old picture. How to remember the new background ?

Comment: @MartinWun you can use shared preferences to save the path and get the path again and set it as background.